# Combo Box (Indirect List)

Tags: excel, list, combobox, userform

Good Morning

I have a userform where I have 2 ComboBoxes:

CB_AppData
CB_App

CB_AppData is an Excel List, whereas CB_App will be a list based in the value of CB_AppData (Basically an indirect function)

So for Example:

```
For Each lAppData In xAppData.Range("App")
Me.CB_AppData.AddItem lAppData.Value
Next lAppData

For Each lRevit In xRevit.Range("Revit")
Me.CB_App.AddItem lRevit.Value
Next lApp

If CB_AppData.Value = ("Revit")
CB_App.Value=lApp
```

However; for the above I can't seem to get it to work, can anyone advise?

Comment: Managed to get it to work this way:

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work this way:

```
If CB_AppData.Value = ("AutoCAD") Then
CB_App.Clear
For Each lApp In xACAD.Range("AutoCAD")
Me.CB_App.AddItem lApp.Value
Next lApp

ElseIf CB_AppData.Value = ("Revit") Then
CB_App.Clear
For Each lApp In xRevit.Range("Revit")
Me.CB_App.AddItem lApp.Value
Next lApp

ElseIf CB_AppData.Value = ("Civil3D") Then
CB_App.Clear
For Each lApp In xC3D.Range("Civil3D")
Me.CB_App.AddItem lApp.Value
Next lApp

ElseIf CB_AppData.Value = ("Plant3D") Then
CB_App.Clear
For Each lApp In xP3D.Range("Plant3D")
Me.CB_App.AddItem lApp.Value
Next lApp

End If
```